# How do I delete everything below row X in VBA/Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long variable X that contains a number.  Say it's 415.

How do I delete everything on the worksheet from Row 415 and below?

I want to ensure my spreadsheet is clean in Row 415 and anything else that might be below it.

How do I do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It sounds like something like the below will suit your needs:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows( X & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
```

Where X is a variable that = the row number ( 415 )

Comment: you can use macro,vba

Answer (score 14):

Another option is `Sheet1.Rows(x & ":" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).ClearContents` (or `.Clear`). The reason you might want to use this method instead of `.Delete` is because any cells with dependencies in the deleted range (e.g. formulas that refer to those cells, even if empty) will end up showing `#REF`. This method will preserve formula references to the cleared cells.

Answer (score 1):

This function will clear the sheet data starting from specified row and column :

```
Sub ClearWKSData(wksCur As Worksheet, iFirstRow As Integer, iFirstCol As Integer)

Dim iUsedCols As Integer
Dim iUsedRows As Integer

iUsedRows = wksCur.UsedRange.Row + wksCur.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
iUsedCols = wksCur.UsedRange.Column + wksCur.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1

If iUsedRows > iFirstRow And iUsedCols > iFirstCol Then
    wksCur.Range(wksCur.Cells(iFirstRow, iFirstCol), wksCur.Cells(iUsedRows, iUsedCols)).Clear
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This helped me. Optional end col and/or row would be even cooler. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Any Reference to 'Row' should use 'long' not 'integer' else it will overflow if the spreadsheet has a lot of data.