# Deleting below a certain variable row in Microsoft Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have code were I have a file of data with unique businesses, the vba that I have programmed removes all other businesses but one. I have noticed that the file that I have worked on has legacy data below the rows filled with data I need and I need to remove these to make the file smaller.

```
Sub ConstructionTools()
    Dim ARange As Range
    Dim DRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsB As Worksheet
    Dim filename As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set wsB = Sheets("Macro")
    Set DRange = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ARange In ws.Range("L1:L28000").Rows
    If ARange(1).Value = "BUILDING CONSTRUCTION" Or ARange(1).Value = "CONSTRUCTION SERVICES" Or ARange(1).Value = "HEAVY & HIGHWAY" Or ARange(1).Value = "HEAVY CIVIL - SPS" Then
        If DRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DRange = ARange
        Else
            Set DRange = Union(DRange, ARange)
        End If
    End If
    Next ARange

    If Not DRange Is Nothing Then DRange.EntireRow.Delete

    With ws.Rows(X & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

I put some code in from here [How do I delete everything below row X in VBA/Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835997/how-do-i-delete-everything-below-row-x-in-vba-excel), but I am getting the

> compile error Invalid or unqualified reference

The code worked before adding in this line

```
With ws.Rows(X & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
```

how would I go about deleting the rows behind the cleaned up data?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? That does not describe the problem. Please explain which line you are getting the error on and what specific error you are getting in your question.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you are deleting rows, you need to use a backward stepping indexed loop, not a for each loop, or the rows get all messed up.

Comment: I added the error message I was getting

Comment: You don't declare or assign X anywhere. Option Explicit 1, you 0, gg.

Comment: Read this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042717/excel-vba-delete-rows

Comment: BraX I tried to recreate the code from the link you gave and I am getting a Run Time error 1004 on the link Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = "TOTAL". My struggle is with my fills I will not know the final end line after removing the unwanted business, but I want to delete rows below. The code looks like it has a constant set for the the number of rows to delete after.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConstructionTools()

'Dim ARange As Range
'Dim DRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim wsB As Worksheet
'Dim filename As String

Set ws = Sheets("Data")
'Set wsB = Sheets("Macro")
'Set DRange = Nothing

Dim RowIndex as long
Dim Counter as long

With ws.Range("L1:L28000")

Dim RowsToDelete() as string
Redim rowstodelete(1 to .rows)

For rowindex = .rows to 1 step -1

Select case .cells(rowindex,1).value
Case "BUILDING CONSTRUCTION", "CONSTRUCTION SERVICES", "HEAVY & HIGHWAY" Or "HEAVY CIVIL - SPS"

Counter = counter + 1
Rowstodelete(counter) = .cells(rowindex,1).address
End select

Next rowindex

End with

If counter >0 then
Redim preserve RowsToDelete(1 to Counter)

With application
.screenupdating = false
.displayalerts = false
.calculation = xlcalculationmanual
 Ws.range(strings.join(RowsToDelete,",")).entirerow.delete
.screenupdating = true
.displayalerts = true
.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic
End if

End sub
```

Untested and written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting. Code attempts to add the addresses of all rows which need to be deleted to an array, and then tries to delete all added rows in one go.